# Can both $x$ and $\sin(x)$ be rational at the same time?

Tags: trigonometry, rationality-testing

> Can both $x$ and $\sin(x)$ be rational at the same time?

Except, of course, trivial $x=0$ case ($\sin0=0$);
$x$ is measured in radians.

The question turned out to be more complicated than it seemed to me at the first sight.

All I came up with, that posed question is equivalent to the question of chord and corresponding arc being together of rational length.

Comment: This might be of interest to you: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NivensTheorem.html

Comment: @Gahawar That doesn't really help, since it only relates $\sin(x)$ with $x/\pi$.

Comment: @Gahawar interesting

Comment: @Arthur I believe the Wikipedia article is more descriptive: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem

Comment: @Gahawar if you claim it to be the answer - sadly it'd not, since it concerns only angles measured in degrees, not in radians.

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze "In radians, one would require that $0 ≤ x ≤ π/2$, that $x/π$ be rational, and that $\sin x$ be rational. The conclusion is then that the only such values are $\sin 0 = 0$, $\sin π/6 = 1/2$, and $\sin π/2 = 1$."

Comment: @Gahawar, so, the answer is No?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If $\sin x$ is rational then
$$ e^{ix} = \pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}+i\sin x $$
is an algebraic number over $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree at most $4$. However, if $x\in\mathbb{Q}^+$ then $e^{ix}$ is a trascendental number, since $e^{i}$ is a trascendental number.

Comment: so, if $sin$ is algebraic, then $cos$ is algebraic too and algebraic  + algebraic $i$ = algebraic ?

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze: yep. On the other hand, $e^{ix}$ cannot be algebraic because that would imply that $e^i$ is algebraic, contradiction.

Answer (score 7):

The [Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) shows that if $\alpha$ is a non-zero algebraic number, then $e^{\alpha}$ is transcendental.

If $\alpha=ix$ when $x$ is rational, then $\alpha$ is algebraic, so $e^{ix}=\cos x + i\sin x$ is transcendental.

If $z$ is transcendental, then so is $w=z-\frac{1}{z}$. Otherwise then $z^2-w z -1 =0$ and thus $z$ is algebraic.

But if $z=e^{ix}$, with $x$ rational, then, $z$ is trascendental and hence so is $z-\frac{1}{z} = 2i\sin x$. So if $2i\sin x$ is transcendental, then so is $\sin x$.